# Changing the file permissions of multiple files through Unix terminal

Tags: file-permissions

Hi I have about a 100 files in a folder and I want to change the file permissions to read write and execute for each file in this folder.

I know how to change the file permissions for a single file i.e. **chmod a+rwx foo.txt**
but not for a group of files. Please help me out

Thank you!

GT

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can use wildcards, like

```
chmod a+rwx *.txt
```

or

```
find <directory> -type f -exec chmod a+rwx {} \;
```

the last command will find all files and exec the chmod per each file.

however, having a+rwx is *not* recommended at all